# afterRender for html binding

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

Is there a way to run custom code after Knockout has added the html to the DOM and finished rendering?  I need this so I can bind a nested view model to dynamically added html code.

Something like:

```
<div data-bind="html: dynamicHtml, afterRender: customCode"></div>

...

MyViewModel.prototype.customCode = function(){
    ko.applyBindings(self.MyInnerViewModel(), document.getElementById('someTagInTheDynamicHtml'));
};
```

`afterRender` is not called here (only works with template binding?), and a custom binding doesn't help either, because the "`update`" event is not guaranteed to be called after the DOM has been updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, [`afterRender`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove) works with `template` binding only.

But you can create custom binding handler that tracks `html` binding changes and fires callback when value is updated. My example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.afterHtmlRender = {
    update: function(el, va, ab){
        ab().html && va()(ab().html);
    }
}
```

Shortened param names: va - *valueAccessor*, ab - *allBindings*.

Also the markup should look like that (binding name is changed):

```
<div data-bind="html: dynamicHtml, afterHtmlRender: customCode"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dDDjf/

**Update**

Simplified binding code with explanations:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.afterHtmlRender = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings){
        // check if element has 'html' binding
        if (!allBindings().html) return;
        // get bound callback (don't care about context, it's ready-to-use ref to function)
        var callback = valueAccessor();
        // fire callback with new value of an observable bound via 'html' binding
        callback(allBindings().html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - works great. I think it should start with 'ab().html()', no? Also, could you please refactor the code in a way people can understand what's going on..?

Comment: No, there should be `ab().html`. It's just check of *html* binding existance among all bindings. I've updated my answer with explanation.